# URL Redirection to another domain with same query parameters

Tags: dns, url-routing, redirect, cloudflare

I bought two domains and I want my users to get redirected when they try to visit `www.mydomain1.com/somepath?somequery` to `www.mydomain2.com/somepath?somequery`. Is it possible using just some service like Cloudflare and not having a dedicated hosting service per se for *mydomain1.com* because the sole purpose of *mydomain1.com* is to redirect to *mydomain2.com* and not to serve any webpage at all?

Comment: You would do this by setting up the domain alias "mydomain1.com" at the host of domain "mydomain2.com". You can then do the redirect in many different ways. I suggest setting up both sites in cloudflare to protect your server, then use a .htaccess or web.config to manage the redirects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using Cloudflare Page Rules. Just add mydomain1.com in your Cloudflare account and create a page rule for URL forwarding with inputs as from:`http://www.mydomain1.com/*` to:`http://www.mydomain2.com/$1`

Comment: you saved my day  not all blogs tell you to add the `$1`